# Why does DomDocument prepend this character (Â) when I use the degree (°) symbol?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a section of code that parses some content from a webpage and I can't figure out why it's inserting the `Â` in front of the degree symbol.

I've replicated what I'm seeing in my application in the php interpreter:

```
$ php -a
php > $dom=new domDocument;
php > $dom->loadHTML("<ol><li>What if I use a ° symbol here...</li></ol>");
php > $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);                                                                                                                                                    
php > $steps = $xpath->query("//li");
php > foreach($steps as $step) { echo $step->nodeValue; }
What if I use a Â° symbol here...
```

Comment: I dont know how to resolve this issue, but I know exactly what this issue is. Â is a character that derives from error during character encoding handling of the PHP parser. PHP does from funky stuff with external and internal encoding of character sets. And Â is what pops up between whitespace during ascii/unciode transformations

Comment: See also: [What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default encoding of `DOMDocument::loadHTML` is  ISO-8859-1, while your input is a UTF-8 encoded string. You need tell to DOMDocument that you're using a different charset.

You can do that with

```
$dom->loadHTML("<?xml encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><ol><li>What if I use a ° symbol here...</li></ol>");
```

Comment: php is notorious for encoding issues. you might want to add a section about source code encoding, internal encoding, input/output encoding, etc... Since it could be any one of these...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an encoding issue?
Normally DomDocument uses UTF-8.

But browsers tend to use different encodings when displaying the page. To force UTF-8 encoding you could add a tag like

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >`
to your head element